# Did the famous French privateer Surcouf really drop that epic zinger on an anonymous British officer?

Tags: france, british-empire, quotes, napoleonic-wars, piracy

It is said that when a British captive officer taunted [Surcouf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Surcouf) with the words "You French fight for money while we fight for honour", Surcouf replied "Each of us fights for what he lacks most". Though I *really* want to believe this interaction happened as stated, I find it difficult to do so given that it has a pungent and unmistakable "and everybody clapped" scent to it.

Furthermore, this [French-language website](https://www.herodote.net/La_guerre_de_course_avec_panache-synthese-2297.php) claims that the quote belongs to his ancestor [René Duguay-Trouin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Duguay-Trouin) and that Surcouf was never made prisoner to begin with.

So did a person ever utter this phrase in its proper context, whether it be Surcouf or another brave Frenchman of the high seas?

Edit: here are some sources. The fact that it appears in Duguay-Trouin's autobiography probably means that it would be the most likely source, but a second opinion or conclusive answer would be nice!

[Storm and Conquest](https://books.google.ca/books?id=llTzWKehyWYC&dq=lacks%20most&pg=PT177&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22lacks%20most%22&f=false)

[That Sweet Enemy (claims the story is improbable)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_t7y4LaBTbUC&dq=surcouf%20each%20of%20us%20fights%20for%20what%20he%20lacks%20most&pg=PA262&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=surcouf%20each%20of%20us%20fights%20for%20what%20he%20lacks%20most&f=false)

[Autobiography of Duguay-Trouin (attributes to himself the quote, with regards to a German officer](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/les-francais-se-battent-pour-le-butin-tandis)

Most other pages point to the quote without any explanation or traceability.

Comment: My understanding is that the prisoner was not Surcouf, but the British officer. They also should have spoken the same language and fluently, to exchange zingers - French seems as a more likely option. Technically, this is a question in history, but people in [French Language SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/) are better qualified for answering it - they are good in finding the origin of words and expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In some cases, Surcouf is the captive and in others the officer is; it depends on the source. However, I have not found an actual primary source, at least not in a book I could access online.

Comment: I don't suppose we could get a rundown of the sources you've found edited into the question? That sounds like a decent amount of research it would be a shame to make interested parties redo (rather than spending their limited time finding new stuff).

Comment: @T.E.D. I added some sources as that is a great idea

Comment: I am familiar with this joke as a professor accusing a student of valuing money over knowledge, to which the student replies with the same punchline - we each want what we don't have. I can't say whether this joke was inspired by Surcouf's, or Surcouf's legend is a variation on the joke - or perhaps just a coincidence.

Comment: @SPavel the same idea (even if less witty) is in *"From everyone according to their abilities, to everyone according to their needs"*

Comment: My memory suggests that the stereotype runs the other way; the French are obsessed with honor and the English "[a nation of shopkeepers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nation_of_shopkeepers)" with money.  I'm a bit surprised to see it reversed here.

Comment: @MCW in my view it is the opposite and the anecdote strengthens the stereotype you described, since the Frenchman in this tale is portrayed as cool but having to hustle and the Englishman as depicted as comparatively lame.

Comment: I posted the question in this sense in French Language SE: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53715/9870

Comment: @RogerVadim merci c'est très apprécié !